# Python: Can I overwrite the __getattr__ in object (built-in)?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I'm trying to prove to myself that I can redefine the syntax of the Python language.  Basically, one of the facets of metaprogramming.  But am struggling to overwrite the behavior of built-in `object` class.

I'm trying to change the behavior where an `AttributeError` is raised when an object has no specific attribute.  Instead I'm trying to force Python to behave like JavaScript, by returning None in the case.  This is an exercise in trying to understand Python's built-ins better, not really a practical problem.

I once I modify it I cannot create objects anymore.  Here is my attempt of modifying the behavior of `object`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class object(type):
    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        return super(object, self).__new__(object, *args, **kwargs)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._dict = {}
        super(object, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        print('GET -> LONG METHOD')
        if key.startswith('_'):
            raise TypeError('Cannot modify built-ins')
        return self._dict.get(key)
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print('GET -> SHORT METHOD')
        if key.startswith('_'):
            raise TypeError('Cannot modify built-ins')
        return self._dict.get(key)
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key.startswith('_'):
            raise TypeError('Cannot set directly on built-ins')
        self._dict[key] = value

class A(object):
    pass

a = A()

a.yay = 7
print(a.yay)
print(a.yup)  # should be None
```

I am not exactly sure what is the `__getattribute__` method but when I inspected `object` I found it had that method instead of `__getattr__`, so I've overwritten both (just in case).

The issue with the code is that during the instatiation of `a = A()` things blow up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 34, in <module>
    a = A()
  File "py.py", line 12, in __new__
    return super(object, self).__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

The error message seems wrong to me.  I am definitely passing at least 1 argument to `__new__` in:

```
return super(object, self).__new__(object, *args, **kwargs)
```

Originally I was not passing that argument at all, since the class should be passed inside `*args` anyway.  The I've added the print statement to the `__new__` method and found that nothing is being passed to it.

**Is it really impossible to change the behavior of the built-ins in Python?  Or I'm just doing it wrong?**

Comment: Even if you succeed you'll only alter new classes that inherit from your fake `object`, and you're causing issues by shadowing the original. Try giving it a different name. Also none of this actually changes the *syntax*.

Answer (score 0):

The particular error you're running into is because you've declared `class object(type)`. This isn't how you declare that you want your class to be a type; all classes are types (unless you're on Python 2 and you make a classic class).

You've declared that you want your class to be a *subclass* of `type`, so all instances of your class will be types. `return super(object, self).__new__(...)` is calling `type.__new__`, which doesn't take what you're passing it.

---

Aside from the above problem, you also have many more problems, some superficial, some fundamental. The most fundamental is that defining your own class named `object` won't do anything to the built-in `object` type. While it's technically possible to screw with the built-in `object` using `ctypes`, it's possible to violate all kinds of language invariants with `ctypes`. Doing so is far from safe.